# Proving $fg$ and $f+g$ is Riemann integrable through the easy and hard way.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> **Problem**: Suppose $f,g$ are Riemann integrable functions, show that $f+g$ and $fg$ are also Riemann integrable.

I know there is really easy to do this with measure theory, but I want to see if this method works as well. I will write an answer for $f+g$ using measures.

> **Write up 1**: Denote $D_f, D_g$ to be the set of all discontinuities of $f$ and $g$. $f+g$ can only be integrable if and only if $D_f \cap D_g$ has measure zero, but without any loss of generality, we also have $D_f \cap D_g \subset D_f$, the set on the left has measure zero. So $f+g$ is Riemann integrable.

Okay this one is the longer one.

> **Write up 2**: As $f$ and $g$ are integrable, there are partitions $P_f$ and $P_g$ such that $$U(f,P_f) - L(f,P_f) < \epsilon/2,$$
>   $$U(g,P_g) - L(g,P_g) < \epsilon/2.$$
>   Now we begin the estimation starting with $$L(f,P)L(g,P) \leq L(fg,P),$$ and $$U(f,P)U(g,P) \geq U(fg, P).$$
>   Therefore if we let $P \supset P_f \cup P_g$ then we get,
>
> \begin{align}
> U(fg,P) - L(fg,P) &\leq U(f,P)U(g,P) - L(f,P)U(g,P) + L(f,P)U(g,P) - L(f,P)L(g,P) \\
> &=U(g,P)[U(f,P) - L(f,P)] + L(f,P)[U(g,P) - L(g,P)]\\
> &\leq \epsilon/2[U(g,P) + L(f,P)]\\
> &\leq \epsilon/2[ U(g,P)  +  \sup \{L(f,P) \}]
> \end{align}

I am stuck with the last step, I am not sure how to bound $U(g,P)$. May I get some pointers?

My futile idea is that I can do the following bound $U(g,P) < \epsilon/2 + L(g,P) < \epsilon/2 + \sup \{L(g,P) \}$

**note**: I know for $fg$, there is another short proof with $4fg = (f+g)^2 - (f - g)^2.$ I am not seeking that one either.

Answer (score 11):

One of your inequalities is not true:
$$
       L(f,P)L(g,P) \le L(fg,P).
$$
If $P$ is a partition of $[0,2]$, and $f$, $g$ are constant and equal to $1$ on $[0,2]$, then
$$
           2*2=L(f,P)L(g,P)\not\le L(fg,P)=2.
$$
**Alternative Method:** You have shown that $f+g$ is Riemann integrable because $f$ and $g$ are. One property you have failed to use is that Riemann integrable functions $f$, $g$ on $[a,b]$ are necessarily bounded in absolute value on $[a,b]$. Because of this, it is possible to reduce to the case where $f \ge 0$ and $g \ge 0$ by adding a constant $L$ to both $f$ and $g$:
$$
         fg = (f+L)(g+L)-L(f+g)-L^{2}.
$$
So, without loss of generality, assume $0 \le f \le K$, $0 \le g \le K$ on the interval of integration for some constant $K$. If $h_{m}$ denotes the greatest lower bound of $h$ on an interval $I$ and $h_{M}$ denotes the least upper bound of $h$ on $I$, then
$$
\begin{align}
    (fg)_{M}-(fg)_{m} & \le f_{M}g_{M}-f_{m}g_{m} \\
                      & =(f_{M}-f_{m})g_{M}+f_{m}(g_{M}-g_{m}) \\
                      & \le K(f_{M}-f_{m})+K(g_{M}-g_{m}).
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
             U(fg,P)-L(fg,P) \le K(U(f,P)-L(f,P))+K(U(g,P)-L(g,P)).
$$
The right side tends to $0$ as $\|P\|\rightarrow 0$ because $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable. So, the left side also tends to $0$ as $\|P\|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: On your first comment, I suppose the same could be said for $U(fg) \leq U(f)U(g)$? Probably a partition over $[0,1/2]$ would work. From your second comment, I assume I did good on write up $1$ ?

Comment: I hadn't looked carefully enough at your write up for #1. For #1, the discontinuities of $f+g$ could be $D_{f}\cup D_{g}$, which is still of measure $0$ if $D_{f}$, $D_{g}$ are of measure $0$.

Comment: May I conjecture then that it is actually $L(f)L(g) \geq L(fg)$ that we have?

Comment: Let $f=x$, $g=1/x$ on $[1,2]$ with a simple partition with one interval $[1,2]$. The $L(f)=1$, $L(g)=1/2$ and $L(fg)=1$ because $fg=1$. So $L(fg) \not\le L(f)L(g)$.

Comment: So basically what I have in the write up and what mixed math has is all wrong?

Comment: Wait, either I am seeing things or you made the same mistake as I did when you have $(fg)M - (fg)m \leq  f_Mg_M - f_m g_m$

Comment: I assumed, without loss of generality, that $f$ and $g$ are non-negative. Is that your concern?

Comment: Yeah, sort of? Basically your counterexample still contradicts the first line even if you assume neither are nonnegative.

Comment: The inequality $0 \le a \le A$ and $0 \le b \le B$ implies $ab \le AB$. That works on each interval. What you were stating is quite different because you are multiplying two sums on the left, and there are cross terms not matched by your sum on the right. That's why yours fails.

Comment: But your counterexample states $f = g = 1 > 0$, yet the final inequality does not hold as you have shown. In an hour, the bounty will end, I will give it to you, but please don't leave me!

Comment: In what I have given you, $K=1$ because $f=g=1$. Because $f$, $g$, and $fg$ are constant, then $U(f)-L(f)=0$, $U(g)-L(g)=0$ and $U(fg)-L(fg)=0$. So $U(fg)-L(fg) \le 1\cdot(U(f)-L(f))+1\cdot(U(g)-L(g))$ holds. Was there another inequality that you were questioning? If you were thinking of the counterexample inequality, I am not saying that the inequality *never* holds; I am saying that it is not *always* true. In other words, there are counterexamples to your inequality, one of which I demonstrated.

Comment: I was referring to the very first one $L(f)L(g) \leq L(fg).$ You have $f = g = 1, fg = 1$, both of which are $\in [0, K]$ for $K \leq 1$.

Comment: My inequality holds for this case because $U(fg)-L(fg)=0$, $U(f)-L(f)=0$ and $U(g)-L(g)=0$, regardless of the interval $[a,b]$ or the partition $P$.

Comment: Wait, no, your inequality doesn't hold. $fg = f = g 1$, so yes of course $U - L = 0$, but you still don't' get $L(f)L(g) \leq L(fg)$.

Comment: No, I don't use that inequality, and I showed you that it doesn't hold. That was an inequality that you were using in write-up #2.

Answer (score 2):

Given a function $f:\ [a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$ and a subinterval $Q\subset[a,b]$ write $\mu(Q)$ for the length of $Q$, and put
$$\|\Delta f\|_Q:=\sup_{x,y\in Q}|f(y)-f(x)|\qquad\bigl(=\sup_{x\in Q} f(x)-\inf_{x\in Q} f(x)\bigr)\ .$$
This $f$ is *Riemann integrable* over $[a,b]$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ into finitely many  subintervals $Q_k$ such that
$$\bigl(U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\bigr)\qquad D_P(f):=\sum_k \|\Delta f\|_{Q_k}\>\mu(Q_k)<\epsilon\ .$$
When $f$ passes this test it is automatically bounded. Furthermore we note that a refinement of $P$ makes $D_P(f)$ smaller.

Now assume that two integrable functions $f$ and $g$ are given. In the following I shall deal with $fg$ only, since $f+g$ is simpler. Then there is an $M>0$ such that both $f$ and $g$ are globally bounded by $M$. From
$$f(y)g(y)-f(x)g(x)=f(y)\bigl(g(y)-g(x)\bigr)+g(x)\bigl(f(y)-f(x)\bigr)$$
it follows that
$$|f(y)g(y)-f(x)g(x)|\leq M\bigl(|f(y)-f(x)|+|g(y)-g(x)|\bigr)\qquad\forall \ x,\>y\in[a,b]\ ,$$
and this implies that for any subinterval $Q\subset[a,b]$ we have
$$\|\Delta (fg)\|_Q\leq M\bigl(\|\Delta f\|_Q+\|\Delta g\|_Q\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
Now let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. By assumption there are partitions $P'$ and $P''$ of $[a,b]$ such that
$$D_{P'}(f)<{\epsilon\over 2M},\quad D_{P''}(g)<{\epsilon\over 2M}\ .$$
Let $P$ be a common refinement of $P'$ and $P''$. Then from $(1)$ it follows that
$$D_P(fg)\leq M\bigl(D_P(f)+D_P(g)\bigr)\leq M\bigl(D_{P'}(f)+D_{P''}(g)\bigr)<\epsilon\ .$$

Comment: I think this one is a little too advance for me...

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck with the last steps of

> $$\begin{align}
> U(fg,P) - L(fg,P) &\leq U(f,P)U(g,P) - L(f,P)U(g,P) + L(f,P)U(g,P) - L(f,P)L(g,P) \\
> &=U(g,P)[U(f,P) - L(f,P)] + L(f,P)[U(g,P) - L(g,P)]\\
> &\leq \epsilon/2[U(g,P) + L(f,P)]\\
> &\leq \epsilon/2[ U(g,P)  +  \sup \{L(f,P) \}].
> \end{align}$$

A key idea is that since both $f$ and $g$ are integrable, the Riemann partition sums $U(g$ and $L(f)$ exist and are finite (I suppress all partition notation - but they're always there). That is, there are some $I_f$ and $I_g$ such that $L(f) \leq I_f \leq U(f)$ and $L(g) \leq I_g \leq U(g)$ for all sufficiently fine partitions, and hence we know the values of $L(f), U(f), L(g), U(g)$ within $\epsilon$.

In particular, $\lvert U(g) \rvert \leq I_g + \epsilon$ and $\lvert L(f) \rvert \leq I_f$. So we finish with the triangle inequality:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert U(g) + L(f) \rvert &\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert U(g) \rvert + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert L(f) \rvert \\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert I_g + \epsilon \rvert + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert I_f \rvert \\
&\leq K\epsilon
\end{align}$$
for a particular but absolute (independent of the choice of partition) constant $K$, and thus is arbitrarily small, concluding the proof.

Comment: Wait, I was just pointed out my first inequality is incorrect. Also, what are your thoughts on my 1st write up?

Comment: Did you also mean $|L(f)| \leq I_f$ and not $\leq I_j$?

Comment: Oh, I admit I did not check your logic. I'll take another look when I wake up.

Comment: Are you awake now…?

Comment: @sidht: Yeah, what's up?

Comment: Were you going to check my work…?